# Accessing Native AudioRecord

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, native, android-audiorecord

I need to access the native AudioRecord class, however it is not exposed via the standard API.

When I attempt to compile code that includes AudioRecord.h using the NDK, it doesn't find the header files.  How do I modify the make files to point to the lib media directories and link with libmedia.so?  I have already downloaded and compiled the android source, I'm just having trouble navigating the android build system.

Is the resulting app going to require rooting the device?

Does anyone have any examples of using the AudioRecord class in native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add directory with media/AudioRecord.h to LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in Android.mk file and add libmedia.so to LOCAL_LDLIBS.

You can see an example here http://code.google.com/p/andless/source/browse/trunk/jni/Android.mk

Comment: Thanks.  Now I am getting a bunch of  error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'android'