# OpenSL on Android 2.1

Tags: android, audio, native

In examining framework options for Android native game development, I came across OpenSL ES as the native sound library of choice.

Then I found that it was added for 2.3.

Is OpenSL ES accessible at all for Android 2.1 and 2.2?  Are there any other audio library options for these versions or am I going to be stuck calling the Android Java audio players from native code?

Thanks!
Dragonwrenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually build and link the libmedia.so into your app.  You will have to build libmedia.so from the android source code for the specific version of android you are running (the library built for 2.1 will not work with 2.2).  Obviously, this is going outside the standard API and is not very portable.  [See this question for a link to a good example of how to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128255/accessing-native-audiorecord)